# 2d games unity vs Flash

Tags: unity, flash, actionscript-3

do people find unity better than flash for 2d games while unity is 3d engine , or Flash still better because it's made for 2d games and flash can get the job done faster ,and now flash is better for ios/android 2d games .
so what platform is the best for 2d games?

Comment: "Which tech to use" questions are off topic for the site: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good

Answer (score 5):

While Flash is still a thriving and vibrant platform to develop on, I would ditch it in favour of Unity, simply considering the unavailability of Flash on some mobile platforms that you may want to port to later.

There is a free package available in the Unity marketplace called [Orthello](http://www.wyrmtale.com/orthello/package), which greatly simplifies the process of making 2d games with Unity.

Finally, if you don't mind tackling new APIs altogether, you should take a look at [haxenme](http://www.haxenme.org/) and [playN](https://developers.google.com/playn/). While toolsets and editors to develop games with these APIs may not be as mature and developed as Unity and Flash, the scope of their cross platform reach is quite impressive, especially playN.